# In the range $0\leq x \lt 2\pi$ the equation has how many solutions $\sin^8 {x}+\cos^6 {x}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

In the range $0\leq x \lt 2\pi$ the equation has how many solutions

$$\sin^8 {x}+\cos^6 {x}=1$$

What i did

$\cos^6 {x}=1-\sin^8 {x}=(1-\sin^4 {x})(1+\sin^4 {x})=(1-\sin^2 {x})(1+\sin^2 {x})(1+\sin^4 {x})$

$\cos^4 {x}=(1+\sin^2 {x})(1+\sin^4 {x}) , \cos^2{x}=0$

$(1-\sin^2{x})^2=(1+\sin^2 {x})(1+\sin^4 {x})$

$-3\sin^2{x}=\sin^6{x}$

Which is not possilbe

Is there a trick or something to solve this equation or to know how many solutions are there ?

Comment: Why is it not possible? $x=0$ is certainly a solution to $-3\sin^2x=\sin^6x$.

Comment: You forgot about the $\cos x = 0$ solution you set off to the side

Comment: i wrote that using comma see in second line

Comment: Use $1 =\sin ^2+ \cos^2 \ge \sin^8 + \cos^6 =1$ to conclude you must have equality so either $\sin x=0$ or $\cos x=0$ hence $4$ solutions in the given interval

Comment: can you elaborate more @Conrad

Comment: That's the solution it given in the marking scheme

Answer (score 9):

One trick is letting $t=\sin^2(x)$, so that the equation reduces to a polynomial $t^4+(1-t)^3 - 1 = t^4 - t^3 + 3t^2 - 3t = t(t^3-t^2+3t-3) = t(t-1)(t^2+3)=0$

Thus either $t=0,1$ so that $\sin(x) = 0,1,-1$. In $[0, 2\pi)$, we clearly have solutions $x=0, \pi, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: (+1) for cleverer substitution than mine :)

Answer (score 5):

We don't need any factorization, indeed since for $x\neq k\frac \pi 2$ we have that $0<|\sin x|<1$ and $0<|\cos x|<1$ then
$$\sin^8 {x}+\cos^6 {x}<\sin^2 {x}+\cos^2 {x}=1$$

we need only to check for the solutions $x= k\frac \pi 2$ which indeed are all the solutions.

Comment: User.Nice answer.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Laziness Is a great virtue in math!

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: @AKADeath We simply need to observe that for any $0<x<1 \implies x^2<x$ and of course $x^n<x^{n-1}<...<x^2<x$. Can you see that? For example $x=0.9 \implies x^2=0.81 <0.90$.

Comment: @AKADeath Therefore since for $x \neq k\pi/2 \implies 0<|\cos x|<1$ we have that $\cos^6 x < \cos^2 x$. For the same reason $\sin^8 x < \sin^2 x$ and then $$\sin^8 {x}+\cos^6 {x}<\sin^2 {x}+\cos^2 {x}=1$$ Which means that for any $x \neq k\pi/2$ the identity never holds. Therefore we only need only to check $x=0,\pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2$ which indeed are solutions.

Comment: User.Wonderful!!Greetings.

Comment: Thanks man v good explanation

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write your equation in the form $$- \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left(  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^
{4}-3\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+4 \right) 
=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\cos x=u\implies \sin x=\sqrt{1-u^2}$. Then $$\sin^8x+\cos^6x=(1-u^2)^4+u^6=(1-4u^2+6u^4-4u^6+u^8)+u^6=1$$ gives $$u^8-3u^6+6u^4-4u^2=0\implies u^2(u^2-1)(u^4-2u^2+4)=0$$ so $u=\cos x=0,\pm1$ as $\Delta_{v^2-2v+4}<0$.

Comment: You forgot $u=-1$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks.